# Open .mtx file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a .mtx file which contains a vector which I am suppose to use for matrix vector multiplication. I tried to open the file using
`fopen('filename')` but this does not work, it returns a single number. I have also tried using readmtx but this gives me the following error: File size does not match inputs. Expected a file size of 232316 bytes. Instead the file size is
365 bytes. Could you please advise how I can open and work with this type of file in MATLAB.

Comment: Is your file MatrixMarket format?

Comment: Yes it is MatrixMarket format

Comment: There's a converter function for that: https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/mm_to_msm/mm_to_msm.html. Matlab's `readmtx` (from the Mapping Toolbox) is not for MatrixMarket files.

Answer (score 0):

`fopen('filename')` outputs only the fileID, which is typically an integer `>3`. This fileID can be used with e.g. `fscanf(fileID)` to get the content of the file.

For the .mtx format, where each line contains [row-number column-number matrix-entry], you could also do something like:

```
%% file
filename = 'my_matrix.mtx';

%% read Matrix
Mat = read_mtx(filename);

%% function
function Mat = read_mtx(filename)
    % open file
    fID = fopen(filename,'r');
    M = fscanf(fID, '%f');
    % reshape M vector into Nx3 matrix
    M = reshape(M, [3, length(M)/3])';
    % assemble final matrix
    Mat = zeros(M(end,1),M(end,1));
    for ii = 1:size(M,1)
        Mat(M(ii,1),M(ii,2)) = M(ii,3);
    end
end
```